# show required checkbox based on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I am new to javascript/jquery and have problem to make the checkbox mandatory based on the value of dropdown list. I want the checkbox is hide and not mandatory if "Guest" is selected, and show the checkbox and make it mandatory if "A/C" is selected. Anyone can help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowHideDiv2() {
    var Payment1 = document.getElementById("Payment1");
    var BCO = document.getElementById("BCO");
    BCO.style.display = Payment1.value == "A/C" ? "block" : "none";
}
</script>

<select name="Payment 1" id="Payment1" editable="true" onchange = "ShowHideDiv2()">
<option value="null" selected>Select... </option>
<option value="A/C">A/C</option>
<option value="Guest">Guest</option>
</select>

<div id="BCO" style="display: none">
<input name="BCO Approved" type="checkbox" value="Yes">
I will pay by A/C.
</div>
```

Comment: There are 4 answers to you question, please let us know if they are not working as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Payment1').change(function(){
var selected = $('option:selected',this).val(); 
if(selected == 'A/C'){
    $('#BCO').show();
}else{
$('#BCO').hide();
}

})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/amyxs34k/2/)

On change event of select get the option selected compare it to `Guest` if same show the div

Answer (score 0):

It will be peace of cake if you use `jQuery`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Payment1").change(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    if($this.val() === "A/C"){
        $("#chBox").css("display","block");
    }else{
        $("#chBox").css("display","none");
    }
  });
});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yt24muq0/)

Answer (score 0):

With pure javascript code, if you wrap your html element in form, you can easily achieve result:

```js
 
function ShowHideDiv2() {
    var Payment1 = document.getElementById("Payment1");
    var BCO = document.getElementById("BCO");
    BCO.style.display = Payment1.value == "A/C" ? "block" : "none";
    document.getElementById("myId").required = (BCO.style.display == "block");
      
}
```

```html
 
<form>
<select name="Payment 1" id="Payment1" editable="true" onchange = "ShowHideDiv2()">
<option value="null" selected>Select... </option>
<option value="A/C">A/C</option>
<option value="Guest">Guest</option>
</select>

  
<div id="BCO" style="display: none">
<input name="BCO Approved" type="checkbox" value="Yes" id="myId">
I will pay by A/C.
</div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
  <form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to do something like this:

```js
var Payment1 = document.querySelector("#Payment1");
var BCO = document.querySelector("#BCO");

function ShowHideDiv2() {
  BCO.style.display = Payment1.value == "A/C" ? "block" : "none";
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var child = BCO.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
  if (BCO.style.display === "block" && !child.checked) {
    alert('Payment by A/C is required.');
  }

});
```

```html
<select name="Payment 1" id="Payment1" editable="true" onchange="ShowHideDiv2()">
  <option value="null" selected>Select...</option>
  <option value="A/C">A/C</option>
  <option value="Guest">Guest</option>
</select>

<div id="BCO" style="display: none">
  <input name="BCO Approved" type="checkbox" value="Yes">I will pay by A/C.
</div>

<p>
  <button>submit</button>
</p>
```